# How to show alignment line between two windows

Tags: wpf

I have windows inside a dock panel which are resizable.
Is there a way to show an alignment line between controls, while dragging or resizing?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can do that using `Adorner` .

Comment: You should at least share a project with your stackpanel and windows people who want to help could play with.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to create a new window wihthout decoration like this:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="640" Height="480" 
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">

    <!-- Content -->

</Window>
```

Then you calculate the placement of your separator line and draw that line in this window. That is the only way I know to draw stuff "between" windows (regardless  of platform, the same is true for any language/toolkit like Qt5, Java Spring etc).